# Shortcuts taking too long to respond

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys, google-chrome, shortcuts

After a normal Ubuntu system update/upgrade some issues started to happen. The most annoying is that some shortcuts are taking too long to respond, like 30 seconds to 1 minute.

Here are some examples:

```
Launch Terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T)
Launch System Monitor (Ctrl+Alt+M): custom commmand "gnome-system-monitor"
Set brightness to 6 (Super+B): custom command "xbacklight -set 6"
```

And while I'm waiting for them to respond, other shortcuts stop working, but they work smoothly if I'm not waiting for other shortcut to respond.

Othe issue that I'm experiencing is a slow Google Chrome browser startup, that began to happen after the same system update.

Comment: Your Ubuntu version?

Comment: You said some issues after an update. Did you reboot after that upgrade? Did you check to make sure your memory usage and disks are not full etc?

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. Yes I have rebooted and checked to see if memory and disk usage were not full.

Comment: Now I'm having issues connecting to new WiFi networks. Not sure if the problems are related.